# Missing space after deleting bootcamp partition

Tags: mac, bootcamp, partition, space

My mac storage has decreased to just 75gb after I deleted Bootcamp. I need to recover this space (45.7gb) and return the computer to the rightful 120gb any help would be much appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe the commands below will return the free space to your "Macintosh HD" volume.

```
diskutil  resizevolume  disk0s3  650M
diskutil  unmount  disk0s3
diskutil  cs  resizestack  7FA484C3-705F-4C19-B060-659CEB006623  0
```

To be sure of the `650M` value, I would first need to see the output from the command given below.

```
diskutil  resizevolume  disk0s3  limits
```

Answer (score 0):

open Disk Utility.app > in toolbar select Partition > click on Partition Button > your missing volume should be on pie-chart as a partition> click on that partition > and look for the - button below the pie-chart. Click on it > apply.